# The meaning of "is right up there"

Tags: meaning-in-context, idiom-meaning, meaning

> Bob Dylan’s first electric tour, the Velvets’ Exploding Plastic
>   Inevitable, the Pistols and Buzzcocks in Manchester ’76. Some gigs
>   continue to resonate for decades after the band leaves the stage. The
>   Pink Floyd and The Soft Machine launching radical paper the
>   International Times at the Roundhouse on October 15th 1966 is right up
>   there.

I can't get the meaning of the last sentence. I know the construction "to be right up with" but it doesn't fit here.

Comment: It means the 1966 launch of IT is right up there (among the few right at the top), alongside other important "milestones" in music, such as Bob Dylan’s first electric tour, the Velvets’ Exploding Plastic Inevitable, the Pistols and Buzzcocks in Manchester ’76.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Still can't get it. Right up there among other newspapers?  But the ones on top aren't newspapers they are events.

Comment: The first "sentence" (which technically speaking is just a list, not a sentence at all) presents several important "events" in the history of modern popular music. They're really important, so we're being invited to imagine a "roll of honour" list of such things, with the most important ones at the top. By implication therefore, the IT launch is being positioned somewhere up near the top of that list of great events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"right up there" means *near the top of the list of the best and greatest*.

Comment: Okay. I think that is the answer I was looking for. Can I say 'popular' in such cases?